# Virtual not permitted on data declarations

Tags: c++, templates

When trying to declare an abstract class, I don't seem to be able to have templated functions.  Why is this, and how do I deal with it?  Here is my example header file.

```
// Foo.h
#include "Bar.h"
#include "Baz.h"
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    virtual Bar<Baz> *getBaz() const = 0;
         //snip
};
```

Other compiler error from the same line includes

> syntax error: missing ';' before '<'

Comment: A member function template cannot be declared virtual.  That said, your class has no member function templates.  Assuming `Bar` is a class template and `Baz` is a type, there is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: What in "Bar.h" and "Baz.h"? Do you have circular includes?

Comment: So if I want all of inheriting classes to implement this member function, how do I go about that?  It would need to be declared virtual, no?

Comment: Yes. What we're asking for is more code so we can fix your problem, because there's nothing wrong with what you posted. I very much suspect circular includes.

Comment: @James McNellis: The member function is not templated. It uses a templated return type but it is fully parametrized and thus a full a real type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I looks like it does not recognize Bar as a type.

Check your two header files and make sure:

1) That it is defined
 2) The include guards are correct and it is not hidden.

Comment: There was a circular dependency.  I'm a complete fool.  Thanks everybody.

Comment: @vapo circular dependency for me aswell, lol